# Exclude output referenced (DLLs) of other projects from project (VSS question)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

This has to do with source control, I'm using VSS and the Visual Studio 2008 plugin. When the DLL of a referenced project gets included in a project (and checked into VSS), on the next build it will fail because those files aren't checked out as part of the build process and will be read only.

I could exclude the entire bin folder and all dlls, but that is where I put my static dlls (ie. the ones that aren't rebuilt as part of the solution) and **interestingly, Visual Studio treats dlls other than outputs of other products as excluded files just fine.**

In VS2005, the VSS plug in didn't automatically add the output of referenced projects as files pending check in, but in VS2008, it does.

Anyone run into this issue or find a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to not check in the bin folders at all. Move the dependencies to a common lib folder, and reference them from there. That will make sure they're copied into the bin folder. You can then explicitly check in this lib folder.

Other files/folders to avoid checking are the obj directory and the ncb file. I'm not sure how "smart" the VSS integration is in this case.

Comment: may want to explicitly say that the Lib folder should be included in your source control

Comment: It's the outputs of reference projects that the VSS plug in is erroneously including.  Visual Studio automatically puts the output of referenced projects into the bin folder.  3rd party things I don't compile, are actually doing just fine (i.e. not included)

Comment: What kind of project is including the files? If I were to guess, I'd expect it to be a Website?